# Array is breaking the code

Tags: php, arrays

This is my code:

```
<?PHP

echo "hello";
$array = ( 
        "hi" => "ho"
        "li" => "lo"
     );

echo "hi";
echo ($array["hi"]);

?>
```

This displays nothing when loaded on the browser. When removing everything that has to do with $array, the browser displayes "hellohi". Am I doing something wrong? Server is Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) running PHP Version 5.1.6. Updating or altering anything in the server is impossible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors in your code. Try the following code:

```
echo "hello";
$array = array(
        "hi" => "ho",
        "li" => "lo"
     );

echo "hi";
echo ($array["hi"]);
```

You were declaring the array wrong ([see manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)), you forgot array(). You were also missing the comma between the array elements.

Comment: I have tried this and it worked. Thanks! Accepting the answer in 8 minutes when it lets me :)

Comment: Cool, also just an fyi, you can do `echo $array["hi"]` instead of `echo ($array["hi"])`

Comment: Thank you, that will save me a bit of time.

Answer (score 3):

missing a `,` in your array,

```
$arr = array("val1" => 1, "val2" => 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

it is

```
$array = array ( 
    "hi" => "ho",
    "li" => "lo"
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your array definition. You need to use the array() function and also place a comma between elements.

What you have as:

```
$array = ( 
    "hi" => "ho"
    "li" => "lo"
 );
```

should instead be:

```
$array = array( 
    "hi" => "ho",
    "li" => "lo"
 );
```

Note the extra function call, and the single extra character after "ho"!

Comment: array() is not a function, it's a language construct.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I didn't want to get into a discussion of precise semantics with someone who's just getting their feet wet in PHP. It's safe to think of array(), unset(), die() and so on as functions when you're getting started.

Answer (score 1):

Declare it as an array. And make sure you have commas

```
<?php

echo "hello";
$array = array( 
        "hi" => "ho",
        "li" => "lo"
     );

echo "hi";
echo $array["hi"];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.4 introduced a javascript-flavored array notation.  With the newest edition your array can be declared as:

```
$array = [ 
  "hi" => "ho",
  "li" => "lo"
];
```

PHP prior to 5.4 will still have to use the extended syntax

```
$array = array(
  "hi" => "ho",
  "li" => "lo"
);
```